# WPF VLC PluginV2 Cache time delay

Tags: wpf, caching, delay, vlc, rtsp

I've hosted the VLC player in my WPF application, in order to play a rtsp stream (from IP camera).
I succeeded to play the rtsp stream from my IP camera.
Unfortunately the vlc adding a delay time (cache time in milliseconds) to the video
He's adding as default 1000ms (one second) delay. I'm trying to find a way to decrease it to 300ms +- at least.
Im trying to do it from my WPF application but I cant find how to do it there is no any examples at google or something like this.
I am using the VLC ACTIVEX PLUGIN V2
Here is my code:

```
vlc = new AxVLCPlugin2(); 
winFormHost.Child = vlc;
vlc.CreateControl();
vlc.playlist.add("rtsp://192.168.2.2/h264?multicast", "First Camera", "--network-caching=300");
vlc.playlist.play();
```

there is any way to do it? , I guess it is something with the options which I dont know how to do it.
I tried to open this at command line:

```
vlc --network-caching=300 -vvv rtsp://192.168.2.2/h264?multicast
```

That open the right thing with the right cache time , but in WPF that not working.
Please if someone can help me

Comment: I also tried to change the default of VLC to cache time 300 MS and its doesn't apply on the wpf application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ":network-caching=300" that works for me using the JavaScript plugin. – mark gamache 20 secs ago